# not all ajax code working online

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'gets/getQuery.php',
data: {'type': $("#type").val(),'isAjax':true},
dataType:'json',
success: function(data) {

   var select = $("#type"), options = '';
   select.empty();    

   options = "<option value=''></option>";    
   for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++)
   {
    options += "<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>"+ data[i].name +"</option>";        
   }

   select.append(options);
}
});
```

where:

```
<select id="type"></select>
```

I'm using this same code about 10 times with different select (different IDs and different getQuery.php file).
On localhost,everything is working fine,however,on online server,only 2 of the selects can read data from php file.

This is the php code of getQuery.php:

```
<?php
include("../db.php");
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
$type = trim($_POST['type']);
$result = array();
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$type);
$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Table order by Type");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

$result[] = array(
  'id' => $row['ID'],
  'name' => $row['Type']
);
}

echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

Anyone knows what might be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: well, is the corresponding *php-code* working?....

Comment: Yes! it is working. Locally everything is perfect.

Comment: .... is the php-code working *on your online server*? with *all possible inputs*? because **that** is where it breaks, since (as you said) your JS behaves differently based on the select that the PHP does. (hint: please show the corresponding PHP...)

Comment: And it's why the PHP code matters: if working fine here and not there, means likely that some PHP config or version differs.

Comment: all php files are copy-paste to each other, only 2 of them displaying data, and all files are running the queries as i run it on server, however i think the problem is in returning the values through ajax.

Comment: I found that the reason is how big the database table is. How can I solve this ? The array displays only tables where there isn't too much data in it

Comment: what is "*too much data*" ? a database can handle tables with millions of records without problem... anyway, you should provide your PHP code since the ajax part seems to be OK

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: "all php files are copy-paste to each other" - BIG code smell. **don't do that**. put the code in a function - *one time* - and use it with parameters. but on a side note: how many datasets are we talking about? you put them all into one array, so the memory-limit could be related.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Yes if I put a condition in the query (Where clause),i can see results,otherwise no.

Comment: @Sally so: *how many datasets*? have you tried increasing or deactivating the memory limit? does your error log indicate anything?

Comment: How can i do so? Sorry I'm not expert in programming